# Enforcing a foreign key to be referenced by at most one other table in Django

Tags: python, database, django

I'm working on a pledge manager for a video gaming charity stream, where users can make donations and have the value of their donation either apply as entries in a raffle OR used for in-game requests OR just as a plain donation. I have a model as follows:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    donator = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    donation = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    note = models.TextField()
```

I'm also planning to create models as follows:

```
class Raffle(models.Model):
    donations = ... # Donation IDs that are allocated to this raffle, perhaps as a ManyToManyField?

class Request(models.Model):
    donations = ... # Donation IDs that are allocated to this request, perhaps as a ManyToManyField?
```

My question: is there a way to have Django enforce a given donation being associated with at most one of Raffle or Request? As it stands right now, it's possible for a donation to be assigned to both, essentially double-counting the donation.

I'm currently using SQLite, although other database engines are options for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to put a `GenericForeignKey` in `Donation` (I'd name the field `reward`) instead of putting `ForeignKey`s in the other tables. Here's [a guide on using GenericForeignKey.](http://axiacore.com/blog/how-use-genericforeignkey-django/)

You will need to make sure that the `GenericForeignKey` points at something that makes sense.